# Gerar Excel no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-excel

Boa tarde.

Eu preciso gerar um arquivo excel pelo SQL SERVER. E eu preciso especificar os tipo de dado das células desse arquivo.

Por exemplo, nas células de valor, setar o tipo de dado como "R$" por exemplo. Em célula com porcentagem, já definir o tipo do dado da célula como "%".

No C# isso é feito com facilidade, mas é possível fazer isso no SQL SERVER?

Tenho a tabela CLIENTE com a seguinte extrutura:

```
NOME               DATANASCIMENTO         VALOR
Thiago Henrique    18-09-1988             52.50
Pedro Diniz        18-09-1988             12.67
```

Preciso gerar um arquivo excel que exporte esses dados onde na planilha a coluna `NOME` tenha o tipo de dado com "Texto", a coluna `DATANASCIMENTO` tenha o tipo de dado "Data Abreviada" e a coluna `VALOR` tenha o tipo de dado "Moeda"

Obrigado pessoal.

Comment: Olá Thiago, sua pergunta está um pouco ampla. Seria mais fácil conseguir uma resposta se você explicasse melhor o que realmente necessita. Por exemplo, já está exportando os dados para Excel? Já tem a consulta? Já tem a fórmula de conversão? Essas e outras informações são necessárias para conseguir uma boa resposta. Se possível também, adicionasse algum exemplo do que realmente necessita.

Comment: @Randrade O que preciso é gerar um excel com o resultado de uma consulta. Não tenho nenhuma fórmula de conversão. Vou adicionar o exemplo.

Comment: Nesse caso você possui duas perguntas. Uma de como exportar e outra de como "customizar" os valores retornados. Sugiro que abra duas perguntas, pois são dois assuntos distintos.

Answer (score 4):

> Estou atualizando a resposta com a forma de exportação via comando SQL.

Você pode apenas copiar e colar os dados em um arquivo excel, como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O SQl Server também possui um "Wizard" para fazer essa exportação. Você pode utilizá-lo da seguinte forma:

**Passo 1:** Clique com o botão direito em cima do banco desejado > Task > Export Data.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso, irá iniciar o Wizard para a exportação. Basta seguir os passos indicados.

**Passo 2:** Selecione o o server e o banco de dados de onde fará a exportação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Passo 3:** Selecione o tipo de arquivo gerado (em seu caso, será **Microsoft Excel**), o local onde será salvo e a versão do excel.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Passo 4:** Neste momento você escolherá entre copiar a tabela ou as tabelas completas (primeira opção) ou adicionar uma query (consulta) para retorno dos dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Passo 4.1:** Copy data from one or more tables or views (Copiar dados de uma ou mais tabelas).

Basta selecionar a tabela ou as tabelas que terão os dados exportados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Passo 4.2:** Write a query to especify the data to transfer (Escrever uma consulta para especificar os dados para transferir)

Basta adicionar a query no campo especificado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Passo 5:** Clique em **concluir** nesta tela ou na posterior:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso, o arquivo estará no local especificado no **Passo 3**.